# KV language and self property

Tags: kivy

For instance I have class and corresponding KV desription like ones provided below. When specifying `drag_rectangle` explicitly - dragging works. But when I am placing there call of property `node_drag_rect` - it doesn't. Why?

```
Builder.load_string('''
<W@Widget>:
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height # It works
    drag_rectangle: self.node_drag_rect  # It doesn't works
''')


class W(DragBehavior, Widget):
    @property
    def node_drag_rect(self):
        return (self.x + 10, self.y + 10, self.width - 20, self.height - 20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how it should be done. Unfortunately Kivy has poor documentation especially in part of observable properties declaration.

Below example how to bind `Color` of widget to Python property:

```
Builder.load_string(f'''
<Interface>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
''')

class Interface(Widget):

    # HERE property should be declared on class level
    # not as usual - in initializer via self.color = ....

    color = ListProperty(palette.PIN_BG_COLOR)  # PIN_BG_COLOR = (.5, .5, 1, 1)


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InterfaceBase, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

When moved property to class level all binding works fine. And don't forget to user Kivy observable properties, not Python's ones.

Answer (score -1):

1) Your kv syntax is wrong, use `<W>` to create a rule to be used with the Python class definition.

2) kv creates automatic bindings to update properties when their dependencies change, e.g. in your first `drag_rectangle: self.x, ...` it will recalculate drag_rectangle when `self.x` changes. In the second case, it has no way to know when `self.node_drag_rect` changes, so the result is never recalculated. This probably causes the drawing to appear wrong.

Comment: So, do you mean that custom created Kivy properties are inaccessible from kv syntax?

Comment: Why do you think that `<W>` is only way to create rule? For instance here I see that this syntax is valid: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes

Comment: I see what you mean. But when declared observable property (for instance kivy.properties.ListProperty) during class instantiation I got `ListProperty is not iterable`. Any ideas?

Comment: No, I don't mean that custom created Kivy properties are inacessible from kv syntax, I'm not even sure what you mean by it. No, I don't think that `<W>` is the only way to create a rule, nor is that what I said. And I can't comment on your out of context error.